# How to create a circle around a selected game object?

Tags: unity-game-engine, png, textures, geometry

I'm creating a simple board game. I have my player (gameObject). I want to create a circle around my player when the player is touched. I've tried to create an quad object and applied a circular texture which i've created in photoshop. But the problem is when I drag the png file onto the game object the entire gameObject is set to the colour of my circle.png

I want something like the effect seen in the image:

[image]

What should I do? Any alternatives? And I want to make the circle to have a heart beat kind of effect.

Please Help. Thank You.

Comment: Why dont you make two diffrent object one for your circle and other for the main game object and put them into a common parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely need an empty parent gameobject to hold the two pieces you want to represent here.  For example, you would create an empty gameobject called "Player."  The Player gameobject has a child gameobject "Player Model" which is the actual 3D representation of the player.  Finally, when the Player Model gameobject is clicked, you can instantiate a third gameobject "Player Selected" as child of "Player" which would be a plane containing your circle texture.

Comment: I've done the same thing already. But thanks anyways for answer.